# Visual Studio Immediate Window & PowerShell

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

As you know Visual Studio's Immediate Window is very limited. You cannot even use loops there.

I am just curious is this possible to integrate PowerShell into Immediate Window? It will make debugging a lot-lot easier.
We will have loops, lambdas etc...

I've thought about [PowerConsole](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/67620d8c-93dd-4e57-aa86-c9404acbd7b3/) but this is not integrated with debugger.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried PowerConsole for this?  I haven't used it lately but I know you can access Visual Studio's DTE object and from there you should be able to grab the Debugger interface e.g. `$dte.Debugger`.

I was just checking out the PowerConsole project site to see if there was a version for VS 2012.  The project owner claims that the NuGet Package Manager Console was a fork of PowerConsole.  And sure enough, this does from the Package Manager Console. I just tried it:

```
$dte.debugger.getexpression("variableName", $true, 2000)
```

Comment: Thanks for this advice. I have also looked at http://studioshell.codeplex.com/ with the same idea.

But it is extremely difficult to use it

When you use `$dte.Debugger.GetExpression` you don't get a real object, you are getting some COM wrapper, which is difficult to use, especially for a non-primitive types

I cannot use something like

`$myVariable = $dte.Debugger.GetExpression("myVariable")`
`$myVariable.MyMethod()`

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to get similar behaviour to being able to iterate/dump some variables and collections in a more flexible way. So I came up with a simple VS Add-In and script for Python Shell with similar functionality. I've placed my project on github - https://github.com/dp0h/VsImmediate